# Full Text query run slow first time and then fast

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, query-optimization, timing

Anyone has some info about this behaviour? I'm running on the same db this query

```
SELECT
                mk.IdMedia                    
            FROM
                mediakeyword mk                  
            WHERE
                MATCH(mk.SearchText) AGAINST('+"france"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0
```

The plan for this

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "mk"    "fulltext"  "SearchText"    "SearchText"    "0" \N  "1" "Using where"
```

SearchText has a FullText Index and the engine is MyISAM

The strange behavior is that first time i run the query the computed time is 2,324 s the second time is 0,015 , why?

There is a way to instruct mysql to have the same second behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FULLTEXT` is available in InnoDB; consider migrating.

There are two things that can lead to "first is slow; second is fast":

- The first time you run a query, it may need to fetch index and/or data blocks from disk.  The second time, those blocks are cached in RAM, therefore much faster.
- The "Query cache", if enabled, records queries and their resultsets.  So, if *exactly* the same `SELECT` is run a second time, it can simply look up the result that was previously computed.

Comment: there is some action to do to force using ram for certain table? in this case mediakeyword ? Why to migrate to InnoDB? Thanks

Comment: Manual attempts to allocate RAM usually backfire.  (And there is no way to do such.)  When you get a corrupt index or inconsistent data or ..., we can discuss why you should have switched to InnoDB.  There are lots of such lists on the web.